# How to move two markers at the same time?

Tags: backbone.geppetto

I am trying to move two markers at the same time with ObjectAnimator and AnimatorSet but I don't get it to work, here I share the code I am using.

```
handler =new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (list.size() > 1 ){

                    if (index < list.size() - 1) {
                        index++;
                        next = index + 1;
                    }
                     if (index < list.size() - 1) {
                         starposition = list.get(index);
                         endposition = list.get(next);
                     }
                    if (index2 < list2.size() - 1) {
                        index2++;
                        next2 = index2 + 1;
                    }
                    if (index2 < list2.size() - 1) {
                        starposition2 = list2.get(index2);
                        endposition2 = list2.get(next2);
                    }
                    final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(marker,"rotation",0,1);
                    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                    objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                            v = objectAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                            logg = v * endposition.longitude + (1 - v)
                                    * starposition.longitude;
                            latt = v * endposition.latitude + (1 - v)
                                    * starposition.latitude;

                            LatLng newpos = new LatLng(latt, logg);
                            marker.setPosition(newpos);
                            marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                            marker.setRotation(getBearing(starposition, newpos));
                        }
                    });
                    final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator2= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(marker,"rotation",0,1);
                    objectAnimator2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    objectAnimator2.setDuration(2000);
                    objectAnimator2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                            h = objectAnimator2.getAnimatedFraction();

                            logg2 = h * endposition2.longitude + (1 - h)
                                    * starposition2.longitude;
                            latt2 = h * endposition2.latitude + (1 - h)
                                    * starposition2.latitude;
                            LatLng newpos2 = new LatLng(latt2,logg2);
                            marker2.setPosition(newpos2);
                            marker2.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                            marker2.setRotation(getBearing(starposition2, newpos2));
                        }
                    });
                    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                    animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimator,objectAnimator2);
                    animatorSet.start();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
            }
        },3000);
```

I have two lists where I store the LatLngs for each marker, then I create the Objectanimator to give the animation to each marker, but ... when I run it, the two do not move at the same time but in a sequential when the first one ends, the other begins to move